# Javascript popup chat like facebook

Tags: javascript, chat

i want to make a popup chat like facebook but i can not put the php code on the javascript ... I found the js chat code in the web (yes, im a scriptkiddie haha), and now i want to appears the messages in the popup window. I want that in popup appears the messages from my database. I planned to use PHP and MySQL, but I can't insert the php code, specifically in:

```
var element = '<div class="popup-box chat-popup" id="'+ id +'">';
element = element + '<div class="popup-head">';
element = element + '<div class="popup-head-left">'+ name +'</div>';
element = element + '<div class="popup-head-right"><a href="javascript:close_popup(\''+ id +'\');">&#10005;</a></div>';
element = element + '<div style="clear: both"></div></div><div class="popup-messages">I WANT TO PUT THE CODE HERE</div></div>';
```

Someone has an idea how to do ?, I thought that a variable "text" which call php could be created, but not really like. Please anyone can help me? :C I started recently in this... Sorry if i don't expressed good, i don't speak english so much...

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong!

```
var element = '<div class="popup-box chat-popup" id="'+ id +'">';
element = element + '<div class="popup-head">';
element = element + '<div class="popup-head-left">'+ name +'</div>';
element = element + '<div class="popup-head-right"><a href="javascript:close_popup(\''+ id +'\');">&#10005;</a></div>';
element = element + '<div style="clear: both"></div></div><div class="popup-messages">I WANT TO PUT THE CODE HERE</div></div>';
```

You need to do this for your element:

```
var element = '<div class="popup-box chat-popup" id="'+ id +'">';
element += '<div class="popup-head">';
element += '<div class="popup-head-left">'+ name +'</div>';
element += '<div class="popup-head-right"><a href="javascript:close_popup(\''+ id +'\');">&#10005;</a></div>';
element += '<div style="clear: both"></div></div><div>; class="popup-messages" id="popup-message"></div></div>';
```

NOTE: this is an example of how you can concatenate the data into a variable, and not a working example of your PopUp. I hope you can go on from here.